# How can I SUMIF with horizontal and vertical criteria (including dates)?

Tags: google-sheets, matrix-multiplication, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to `SUMIF` data based on two criteria:

1. The title of the column (horizontal)
2. In between two dates (vertical)

I have tried a number of functions to solve this problem but to no avail.

[image: 0]

I have tried functions with Match, Index, and Filter, but I couldn't make the function work.

As you can see in my code, I have found a workaround, but it is not ideal as it does not use the table header to identify the data values I'm looking for (see example function below for Product A).

`=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&A$2,A:A,"<="&A$5)`

I'm hoping for a function that can dynamically grab the values I'm looking for, based on the table header and the dates.

Thank you for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use index/match to select just the relevant column of the range (where a zero in the row parameter indicates the entire column):

```
=sumifs(index($B2:$D,0,match(F1,$B1:$D1,0)),$A2:$A,">="&$A2,$A2:$A,"<="&$A5)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked superbly. And it was easy to implement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({B1:D1; TRANSPOSE(MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:D, A2:A>=A3, A2:A<=A5)), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(10, 
 COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B, A2:A>=A3, A2:A<=A5))), 1))^0))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution! As with Tom's suggestion, this also worked well, but I found his solution easier to understand and implement.

Answer (score 0):

[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRDPm.png)

Summary Required :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGtdB.png)

Formula : =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("C"& MATCH(B15,$B$2:$B$10,0)+1 & ":" & "G"& MATCH(B15,$B$2:$B$10,0)+1),$C$1:$G$1,">="&DATE(2022,2,1),$C$1:$G$1,"<="&DATE(2022,2,28))

Comment: Please post code rather than images. It's better to follow and understand.